# ASP.NET Core MVC 1.3 Web API + Entity Framework, I can't search a database by name, but I can by id

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm an absolute beginner with .NET and I'm unable to fix this.

Currently I have this:

Hotel.cs (Model)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Hotels.Models
{
    public class Hotel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string image { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string features { get; set; }
        public bool featured {get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in my controller I have a function that searches an hotel by its id

```
[HttpGet("{id}",Name="GetHotelById")]
public ActionResult<HotelReadDto> GetHotelById(int id)
{
    var hotelItem = _repository.GetHotelById(id);

    if(hotelItem != null)
    {
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<HotelReadDto>(hotelItem));
    }
    
    return NotFound();
}
```

The functions are defined in this interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Hotels.Models;

namespace Hotels.Data
{
    public interface IHotelsRepo
    {
        bool SaveChanges();
        IEnumerable<Hotel> GetAllHotels();
        Hotel GetHotelById(int id);
        void UpdateHotel(Hotel cmd);
    }
}
```

And this is where the interface is implemented

```
  public Hotel GetHotelById(int id)
  {
       return _context.Hotels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
  }
```

Right now if I search by id, for example

```
GET /api/hotels/1
```

it returns a value.

If in all the above functions I change (int id) , by (string name) and latter on I look for

```
GET /api/hotels/hotel1
```

It always returns a 404.

This is what I basically change

Controller

```
public ActionResult<HotelReadDto> GetHotelById(string name)
{
    var hotelItem = _repository.GetHotelById(string name);

    if (hotelItem != null)
    {
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<HotelReadDto>(hotelItem));
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

Interface

```
Hotel GetHotelById(string name);
```

And then the repo

```
public Hotel GetHotelById(string name)
{
    return _context.Hotels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == name);
}
```

But it still returns a 404, I'm a bit lost with how could I change it to look for name instead of id

Comment: Does you app call the right URL? 404 means the API was not found. Probably a config issue. Not so much with you code... Check your API is running. Check config/env is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the attribute above the method still the following?

```
[HttpGet("{id}",Name="GetHotelById")]
public ActionResult<HotelReadDto> GetHotelById(string name)
```

If so, try changing it to this:

```
[HttpGet("{name}",Name="GetHotelById")]
public ActionResult<HotelReadDto> GetHotelById(string name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put route config attribute on action method or you have to change the route in route config.